# span next to input-tag while input tag takes the full width

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this:

I want to place a range slider next to an output tag. Both tags should be on the same line while the input range slider takes the full width of the given space.

Problem: I have to

```
display:block
```

the span element, because i want to set a fix width. This and the

```
width:100%;
```

for the range slider makes it impossible (for me) to achieve my goal.

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MerE6/1/).

So, how can i achieve this?

- fixed width for the output tag
- output and input should be sitting side-by-side on one line
- the input slider should be taking the full width of the given space

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a way to set a width for the output tag without display:block? Because i want to avoid floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `float` and IE8 and above supported way
use `display:table`

<kbd>[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MerE6/7/)</kbd>

```
  .form-inline {
        display:table;
        border:1px solid green;
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .input_button {
        display:table-cell;
        width:104px; /* Fixed span width*/
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #range_slider {
        border:1px solid red;
        display:table-cell;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set left float on span and instead of giving range slider a width of 100%, give span 19% and range slider 78%. You need to divide 100% among themselves.

```
.input_button{
float:left;
    width:19%;
}
#range_slider{
    width:78%;
    margin-top:33px;
        margin-left:10px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MerE6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting **display:block** for span element, try Can using **display:inline-block**